# Definitions of Measurability: Outer-inner measure convergence vs. Caratheodory criterion

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure, measurable-sets

If we are looking over subsets of $\mathbb R$ and considering the outer measure defined exactly as
$$\mu^*(A) = \inf\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k) \text{ where the $I_k$ are open intervals such that } A\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k \right\}$$
and inner measure to be

$$\mu_*(A) = \sup\left\{\mu^*(F) \text{ where the $F$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ such that } F\subset A \right\}$$

then measurability **in the sense of Lebesgue:**

- **$A$ is measurable if $\color{red}{\mu^*(A)=\mu_*(A)}$**

is equivalent to the **Caratheodory criterion:**

- **$A$ is measurable if $\color{red}{\mu^*(T) = \mu^*(T\cap A) + \mu^*(T\cap A^C)}$ for all test sets $T\subset \mathbb R$**

See the proof from page 41-45 of this pdf: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/212a/11.pdf; definitions and preceding theorems are found pages 1-40).

First question $\color{red}{\text{STILL OPEN}}$ (perhaps refer to Nate’s comment below)?:

> If these two definitions are in fact equivalent, ***has anyone tried proving the Caratheodory Extension Theorem without the Caratheodory criterion***, i.e. from scratch using outer and inner measure, or at least the equivalent definition of $\color{red}{\mu(G\setminus F)<\epsilon \text{ for some } G\supset A\supset F}$ (the "inner-outer" characterization from the Harvard pdf)? If so, could you provide a rundown of the proof (or a link to some article)?
>
> If it doesn't work generally, how about in the specific case where outer measure is defined the way I defined it above (e.g. as in the proof presented here, page 28 of the pdf: https://www.stat.washington.edu/jaw/COURSES/520s/521/bk521reJaw2012.pdf)?

And second question $\color{red}{\text{(resolved I believe by the comment by Daniel Fischer)}}$:

> Consider a weaker criterion than Caratheodory's: I just want that $\mu^*(X) = \mu^*(X\cap A) + \mu^*(X\cap A^C)$ for just the "biggest set" $X$ (I'm talking about the set for which $A^C=X\setminus A$ for all $A$, i.e. the universal set; assume also that $\mu(X)$ is not infinite). We are still using outer measure as I defined it above.
>
> Is this an equivalent condition to the notions of measurability I described before? If not, is there an explicit counterexample (one that I can use pedagogically to motivate Caratheodory's stronger criterion)?

Related questions:

- [Intuition behind the definition of a measurable set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485815/intuition-behind-the-definition-of-a-measurable-set)
- [Proving the *Carathedory Criterion* for *Lebesgue Measurability*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064678/proving-the-carathedory-criterion-for-lebesgue-measurability)
- [Measurability criterion of Caratheodory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563720/measurability-criterion-of-caratheodory?rq=1)
- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34007/demystifying-the-caratheodory-approach-to-measurability
- [Proving equivalent of definitions of measurability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897325/proving-equivalent-of-definitions-of-measurability)
- [Is the Carathéodory definition of Measurable set the most general?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186305/is-the-carath%C3%A9odory-definition-of-measurable-set-the-most-general/3068341)

**$\color{red}{\text{Thanks to Daniel Fischer to a comment for what I believe to be a resolution to Question 2:}}$**

- [Proving Caratheodory measurability if and only if the measure of a set summed with the measure of its complement is the measure of the whole space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008508/proving-caratheodory-measurability-if-and-only-if-the-measure-of-a-set-summed-wi)

Comment: Re your second question, if $\mu(X) < +\infty$, your condition [is equivalent to Carathéodory measurability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008508/proving-caratheodory-measurability-if-and-only-if-the-measure-of-a-set-summed-wi). The two are (generically) not equivalent if $\mu(X) = +\infty$, since then $\mu(X) = \mu^{\ast}(A) + \mu^{\ast}(X\setminus A)$ for all $A \subset X$. Re the first question, I think I have read somewhere that it's possible. But it would be very awkward, I guess.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the link. Do you mind writing out (or linking to) an explicit example for the infinite case where my condition says “it’s $\mu^*$-measurable” when in fact the other conditions say it’s not?

Comment: Oy vey. An explicit example of a non-measurable set is hard to come by. If AC doesn't hold (in which particular way it would need to fail would be a question on which Asaf may be able to shed light) it is possible that _every_ subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue-measurable. On different measurable spaces, explicit examples may be easy to construct, however.

Comment: To my mind, the Caratheodory extension theorem in this context is the statement that "the collection of measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra and the outer measure is countably additive on this $\sigma$-algebra".  Which is exactly what Sternberg proves in slides 27-38.  So if that is not what you are looking for, then perhaps you could precisely state the result you want to see proved.

Comment: @NateEldredge his proof is so short! In three slides he proved the extension theorem (and then went on to talk about open and closed sets)?! If someone can prove that so quickly why need Carathéodory at all?

Comment: Version 18 of the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes; I put a bounty on the question and no one answered so I'm hoping someone will answer so I can award a bounty to someone. I want to maximize the chance that someone with an answer stumbles across the page in the time that's left, and I know of no other method.

Comment: Putting on the bounty is the way to increase the chances. Innumerable edits is abusing the site. Please stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the first question, it can be done for the Lebesgue measure, but the proof is long. I taught it like that once, but I was not happy with it.
I am not taking the intervals to be open (it is equivalent).

$$
\mu^{\ast}(E):=\inf\left\{  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ell(R_{i}):~R_{i}\text{
intervals, }\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}R_{i}\supseteq E\right\}  .
$$

Given a set $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, we say that $E$ is *Lebesgue
measurable* if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an open set $U\supseteq
E$ such that
$$
\mu^{\ast}(U\setminus E)\leq\varepsilon.
$$

**Proposition 1**
The following properties hold.

(i) If $E\subseteq F\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then $\mu^{\ast}(E)\leq
\mu^{\ast}(F)$.

(ii) If $E\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$, then $\mu^{\ast
}(E)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^{\ast}(E_{n})$.

(iii) If $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
\mu^{\ast}(E)=\inf\{\mu^{\ast}(U):~U\text{ open, }U\supseteq E\}.
$$

(iv) If $E,F\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $\operatorname*{dist}(E,F)>0$,
then $\mu^{\ast}(E\cup F)=\mu^{\ast}(E)+\mu^{\ast}(F)$.

**Proof:** (i) If $R_{i}$ are intervals such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}
R_{i}\supseteq F$, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}R_{i}\supseteq E$, and so
$$
\mu^{\ast}(E)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ell(R_{i}).
$$
Taking the infimum over all sequences of intervals covering $F$ gives
$\mu^{\ast}(E)\leq\mu^{\ast}(F)$.

(ii) If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^{\ast}(E_{n})=\infty$, there is nothing to
prove. Thus, assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^{\ast}(E_{n})<\infty$. Given
$\varepsilon>0$, for each $n$ find a sequence $\{R_{i}^{\left(  n\right)
}\}_{i}$ of intervals such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}R_{i}^{(n)}\supseteq
E_{n}$ and such that
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\ell(R_{i}^{(n)})\leq\mu^{\ast}(E_{n})+\frac
{\varepsilon}{2^{n}}.
$$
Since $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable, we may write $\{R_{i}
^{(n)}\}_{i,n\in\mathbb{N}}=\left\{  R_{j}\right\}  _{j\in\mathbb{N}}$. Note
that
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}R_{j}=\bigcup
\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}R_{i}^{\left(  n\right)  },
$$
and so by part (i) and (by properties of nonnegative double series)
$$
\mu^{\ast}(E)\leq\mu^{\ast}\left(  \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}\right)
\leq\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\ell(R_{j})=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\ell(R_{i}^{\left(  n\right)  })\leq\sum
\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^{\ast}(E_{n})+\varepsilon.
$$
By letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow0^{+}$ we conclude the proof.

(iii) If $U$ is open and $U\supseteq E$, then by part (i), $\mu^{\ast}
(E)\leq\mu^{\ast}\left(  U\right)  $. Taking the infimum over all open sets
containing $E$ gives
$$
\mu^{\ast}(E)\leq\inf\left\{  \mu^{\ast}(U):~U\text{ open, }U\supseteq
E\right\}  .
$$
On the other hand, if $R_{i}$ are intervals such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty
}R_{i}\supseteq E$, given $\varepsilon>0$ for every $i$ consider an open
interval $T_{i}\supseteq R_{i}$ such that $\operatorname*{meas}T_{i}
\leq\operatorname*{meas}R_{i}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{i}}$ and let
$V:=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}T_{i}$. Then $V$ is open and contains $E$ and so
$$
\inf\left\{  \mu^{\ast}(U):~U\text{ open, }U\supseteq E\right\}  \leq\mu
^{\ast}(V)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ell(T_{i})\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ell
(R_{i})+\varepsilon.
$$
Letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow0^{+}$ gives
$$
\inf\left\{  \mu^{\ast}(U):~U\text{ open, }U\supseteq E\right\}  \leq
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ell(R_{i}).
$$
Taking the infimum over all sequences of intervals covering $E$ gives
$$
\inf\left\{  \mu^{\ast}(U):~U\text{ open, }U\supseteq E\right\}  \leq\mu
^{\ast}(E).
$$

(iv) Let $d:=\operatorname*{dist}(E,F)$. If $R_{i}$ are intervals such that
$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}R_{i}\supseteq E\cup F$, by subdividing each interval
$R_{i}$ into subintervals, without loss of generality, we may assume that each
interval $R_{i}$ has diameter less than $d$. Hence, if $R_{i}$ intersects $E$
it cannot intersect $F$ and viceversa. Write $\{R_{i}:~R_{i}\cap
E\neq\emptyset\}=\{S_{i}\}$ and $\{R_{i}:~R_{i}\cap F\neq\emptyset
\}=\{T_{i}\}$. Then $\bigcup_{i}S_{i}\supseteq E$, $\bigcup_{i}T_{i}\supseteq
F$ and so
$$
\mu^{\ast}(E)+\mu^{\ast}(F)\leq\sum_{i}\ell(S_{i})+\sum_{i}\ell(T_{i}
)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ell(E_{i}).
$$
Taking the infimum over all sequences of intervals covering $E\cup F$ gives
$$
\mu^{\ast}(E)+\mu^{\ast}(F)\leq\mu^{\ast}(E\cup F).
$$
The other inequality follows from part (ii).

**Proposition 2**
The following properties hold.

(i) Open sets are Lebesgue measurable.

(ii) If $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ has Lebesgue outer measure zero, then
$E$ and its subsets are Lebesgue measurable.

(iii) If $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$, and each $E_{n}$ is Lebesgue
measurable, then $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.

(iv) Compact sets are Lebesgue measurable.

(v) Closed sets are Lebesgue measurable.

(vi) If $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, then
$\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ is Lebesgue measurable.

(vii) If $E=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$, and each $E_{n}$ is Lebesgue
measurable, then $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.

**Proof** (ii) Let $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\mu^{\ast}(E)=0$. By
Proposition 1(iii),
$$
0=\mu^{\ast}(E)=\inf\left\{  \mu^{\ast}(U):~U\text{ open, }U\supseteq
E\right\}  .
$$
Hence, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $U$ open such that $U\supseteq
E$ and $\mu^{\ast}(U)\leq\varepsilon$. By Proposition
1(i), $\mu^{\ast}(U\setminus E)\leq
\mu^{\ast}(U)\leq\varepsilon$, and thus $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Again by Proposition 1(i), if $F\subseteq
E$, then $0\leq\mu^{\ast}(F)\leq\mu^{\ast}(E)=0$, and so $F$ also has Lebesgue
outer measure zero, and thus is Lebesgue measurable.

(iii) Let $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}$, where each $E_{n}$ is Lebesgue
measurable. Then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an open set
$U_{n}\supseteq E_{n}$ such that
$$
\mu^{\ast}(U_{n}\setminus E_{n})\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n}}.
$$
Define $U:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_{n}$. Then $U$ is open, contains $E$ and
$U\setminus E=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(U_{n}\setminus E)\subseteq\bigcup
_{n=1}^{\infty}(U_{n}\setminus E_{n})$. Hence, by Proposition
1(i) and (ii),
$$
\mu^{\ast}(U\setminus E)\leq\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^{\ast}%
(U_{n}\setminus E_{n})\leq\varepsilon.
$$
(iv) Let $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a compact set. Then $K$ is bounded and so
$\mu^{\ast}(K)<\infty$. Then by Proposition
1(iii) for every $\varepsilon>0$ there
exists an open set $U\supseteq K$ such that
$$
\mu^{\ast}(U)\leq\mu^{\ast}(K)+\varepsilon.
$$
The set $U\setminus K$ is open and so we can write
$$
U\setminus K=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}Q_{n},
$$
where $Q_{n}$ are closed bounded intervals with disjoint interior. Hence, for
every $m\in\mathbb{N}$ the set
$$
C_{m}:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{m}Q_{n}
$$
is compact and does not intersect $K$. Hence, $\operatorname*{dist}%
(C_{m},K)>0$. Since $K\cup C_{m}\subseteq U$, by Proposition
1(i), (iv),
\begin{align*}
\mu^{\ast}(U) &  \geq\mu^{\ast}(K\cup C_{m})=\mu^{\ast}(K)+\mu^{\ast}(C_{m})\\
&  =\mu^{\ast}(K)+\sum_{n=1}^{m}\ell(Q_{n})
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{m}\ell(Q_{n})\leq\mu^{\ast}(U)-\mu^{\ast}(K)\leq\varepsilon
$$
for all $m$. Letting $m\rightarrow\infty$ gives
$$
\mu^{\ast}(U\setminus K)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ell(Q_{n})\leq\mu^{\ast
}(U)-\mu^{\ast}(K)\leq\varepsilon,
$$
which shows that $K$ is measurable.

(v) If $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is closed, then $C=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}
(C\cap\lbrack-n,n])$ and since each $C\cap\lbrack-n,n]$ is compact, it follows
from parts (iii) and (iv) that $C$ is measurable.

(vi) If $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, then for every
$n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists an open set $U_{n}\supseteq E$ such that
$$
\mu^{\ast}(U_{n}\setminus E)\leq\frac{1}{n}.
$$
By part (v) the set $C_{n}:=\mathbb{R}\setminus U_{n}$ is closed and so
Lebesgue measurable. Define $F:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}$. Then $F$ is
Lebesgue measurable by part (iii). Since $U_{n}\supseteq E$, we have that
$\mathbb{R}\setminus E\supseteq\mathbb{R}\setminus U_{n}=C_{n}$ for every $n$,
and so $\mathbb{R}\setminus E\supseteq F$. Moreover,
$$
(\mathbb{R}\setminus E)\setminus F=(\mathbb{R}\setminus E)\setminus
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\subseteq U_{n}\setminus E
$$
for every $n$ and so
$$
\mu^{\ast}((\mathbb{R}\setminus E)\setminus F)\leq\mu^{\ast}(U_{n}\setminus
E)\leq\frac{1}{n}.
$$
Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$ shows that $\mu^{\ast}((\mathbb{R}\setminus
E)\setminus F)=0$ and so $(\mathbb{R}\setminus E)\setminus F$ is measurable by
part (ii). Since $F$ is measurable, we have that $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ is
Lebesgue measurable since it is the union of $F$ and $(\mathbb{R}\setminus
E)\setminus F$.

(vii) This follows from part (vi) and De Morgan's laws.

**Remark**
In the proof of part (iv) we used the fact that
$$
\mu^{\ast}(C_{m})=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\ell(Q_{n}).
$$
To see this, if $Q_{n}$ has length $\ell_{n}$, consider the intervals with the
same center $S_{n}$ of length $(1-\varepsilon)\ell_{n}$. Since the intervals
$Q_{n}$ have pairwise disjoint interior, it follows that $\operatorname*{dist}
(S_{n},S_{k})>0$ for $n\neq k$ and so by Propositions
1
(iv)
\begin{align*}
\mu^{\ast}(C_{m}) &  \geq\mu^{\ast}\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{m}S_{n}\Big)=\sum
_{n=1}^{m}\mu^{\ast}(S_{n})\\
&  =\sum_{n=1}^{m}\ell(S_{n})=\sum_{n=1}^{m}(1-\varepsilon)^{N}\ell(Q_{n}).
\end{align*}
Letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow0^{+}$ gives
$$
\mu^{\ast}(C_{m})\geq\sum_{n=1}^{m}\ell(Q_{n}).
$$
The other inequality follows from Proposition 1(ii).

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer! Do you know if there are any published books that do things this way (at least for Lebesgue)? It's not too long (definitely not longer than the Caratheodory approach), and I think is more intuitive than, and would serve as good practice/training for, the more "abstract" Caratheodory proof.

Comment: There is a book of Jones titled Lebesgue integration on Euclidean space